# Get custom data from multidimensional array php

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array, treeview

I have directory array

```
[{"10000":[]},{"10006":[]},{"10011":[]},{"TEST1":[{"10011":[]},{"11111_old":[]}]},{"TEST2":[{"10000":[]},{"10001":[{"10000":[]}]},{"10007":[{"10006":[]}]}]},{"TEST3":[{"10006":[]},{"10012":[{"10011":[]}]}]}]
```

when json_decode `$dir_array = json_decode($treedata,true);` , i show it in tree view data in webpage like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV4Fy.png)

So when i click on 1st level 10000 i get key 10000 as text i.e 1st key but when i click on 2nd level 10007 i get its key as text same 10007, i want to get text like "TEST2/10007" instead of only text "10007".

Same for 3rd level hierarchy when i click on 10011, i only get 10011 key as text instead of "TEST3/10012/10011"

Can i get data as text for above when i click on specific i.e `"10000", "TEST2/10007", "TEST3/10012/10011"`.

Just want to get TOP to LAST Structure as TEXT when click on Last element from array.

Updated code

```
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function downloadspecificcompany(cmp)
      {
        console.log(cmp);
        if(cmp.toString().indexOf("http") != -1){
            console.log("Some folder found not company -->"+cmp);
            var arr = cmp.toString().split('/'); 
            console.log(arr);
            var cmp = arr[3];
            console.log("ompany found-->"+cmp);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("company found-->"+cmp);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <!-- Treeview starts -->

    <script src="js/file-explore.js"></script> 
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/file-explore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        body{font-family:'Roboto',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color:#fafafa;}
        .container { margin:150px auto; max-width:728px;}
    </style>
    <!-- $(".file-tree").filetree();  -->
  <!-- Treeview ends -->
</head>
<body>

<?php


$dir = "/usr/share/Data/rahul/";
/*
This is directory folder
├── 10000
├── 10000_Backup
│   └── 10000
├── 10006
├── 10011
├── 10011_Backup
│   └── 10011
├── TEST1
│   ├── 10011
│   └── 11111_old
├── TEST2
│   ├── 10000
│   ├── 10001
│   │   └── 10000
│   └── 10007
│       └── 10006
└── TEST3
    ├── 10006
    └── 10012
        └── 10011
*/

$a1 = listFolders($dir);
$treedata = json_encode($a1);
function listFolders($dir)
{
   $dh = preg_grep("/(\w+)_Backup/", scandir($dir), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
   $return = array();
   foreach ($dh as $folder)
   {
       if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..')
       {
           if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $folder))
           {
               $return[] = array($folder => listFolders($dir . '/' . $folder));
           }
       }
   }
   return $return;
}

$dir_array = json_decode($treedata,true);
function mygenerateTreeMenu($dir_array,$limit = 0)
{
    $key = '';
    $tree = '';
    if ($limit > 1000) return '';
    foreach ($dir_array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!is_int($key))
        {
            $tree .= "<li class='treeclass'>";
            $tree .= "<a href='#' onclick='downloadspecificcompany($key);'  id='".$key."'>$key</a><ul>";
            $tree .= mygenerateTreeMenu($value,$limit++);
            $tree .= "</ul></li>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if($key>100){
                $tree .= "<li  class='treeclass'>";
                $tree .= "<a  href='#' onclick='downloadspecificcompany($key);' id='".$key."'>$key</a><ul>";
                $tree .= mygenerateTreeMenu($value,$limit++);
                $tree .= "</ul></li>\n";
            }
            else{
                $tree .= mygenerateTreeMenu($value,$limit++);
            }
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
echo "<ul class='file-tree' style='padding-left: 0px;'>\n";
$finaltree = mygenerateTreeMenu($dir_array);
echo $finaltree;
echo "</ul>\n";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Onclick i pass $key  to my javascript function i,e downloadspecificcompany($key) & do my specific task. Problem is i want to pass whole text like "TEST3/10012/10011" instead of $key i.e 10011

Comment: OK i will update my whole php embedded code in question, than you can get idea.